# Name of my app not showing on top of activity. Showing "com.example.(appname).(file name)

Tags: android

When first starting a simple app, usually the title of the app is on the top of the activity. However, for me, it says `com.example.inventory.MainActivity` and then when I switch activities to another one, it'll say `com.example.inventory.AddProduct`

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.inventory">
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ProductList"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddProduct" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm a beginner so sorry if I forgot to include any other important file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a label for your activity like this:

```
   <activity android:name=".ProductList" 
   android:label = "Product Screen"></activity>
```

Replace Product Screen with the Title of your choice.
Do the same for all the other activities in the Manifest.xml